# Placing my USB 3.0 expansion card into the second PCI-E slot leads to the computer being stuck

Tags: usb, pci-express, ubuntu-18.04

I intend to connect four USB cameras to the computer to do some experiments, so I bought a USB 3.0 expansion card with four ports.

I originally had a graphics card (GeForce GTX 1080) in the first PCI-E slot, so I plug the USB card into the second slot. But When I open four cameras simultaneously, the computer freezes in a few seconds and does not respond to any operation.

But the strange thing is that when I exchange slots for USB card and GTX 1080, they all work fine.

My motherboard is ASUS PRIME Z270-P.

I also did the following experiment:

- If there is only GeForce GTX 1080 , then no matter which slot it is in, it works well.
- If there is only expansion card, It can only be in the first slot or my computer freezes.

I am very confused now, why does the USB card conflict with the second PCI-E slot?

Comment: Do both slots have the same number of pins?  Does the BIOS have any settings related to the slots?

Comment: I don't think they conflict. This might be more related to priority on the motherboard bus, where slot position is important.

Comment: @JakeGould Thank you for your reply, I've added information about my motherboard. Both of the two slots are 16x. Sure, it works only if the USB card in the first slot and graphics card in the second slot, but I want to know why.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune Yes, Both of the two slots are 16x.